# Jboss 4.2.3 migration to Jboss 7 EAP, datasources and security

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jboss-eap-7, jboss-4.0.x

I want to migrate several Java applications from **Jboss 4.2.3** to **Jboss 7.0.0 EAP**.

For the first step, I decided to migrate datasources.
For example I have such datasource config in 4.2.3:

```
{profile}/deploy/some-ds.xml
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>SomeDS</jndi-name>
    ...
    <security-domain>EncryptedSomeDBLocalRealm</security-domain>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

But I have noticed that datasource credentials are encrypted and thus I also need to migrate security system.
There are related configs in 4.2.3:

```
{profile}/conf/login-config.xml
<application-policy name = "EncryptedSomeDBLocalRealm">
    <authentication>
       <login-module code = "org.jboss.resource.security.JaasSecurityDomainIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
             <module-option name = "username">user123</module-option>
             <module-option name = "password">1ad9fNmTA/65Ufh583ZAn4</module-option>
             <module-option name = "managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=SomeDS</module-option>
             <module-option name = "jaasSecurityDomain">jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityDomain,domain=ServerMasterPassword</module-option>
       </login-module>
    </authentication>
</application-policy>

{profile}/conf/jboss-service.xml
<mbean code="org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityDomain"
  name="jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityDomain,domain=ServerMasterPassword">
  <constructor>
     <arg type="java.lang.String" value="ServerMasterPassword"/>
  </constructor>
  <attribute name="KeyStorePass">{CLASS}org.jboss.security.plugins.FilePassword:${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.password</attribute>
  <attribute name="Salt">abcdefgh</attribute>
  <attribute name="IterationCount">19</attribute>
</mbean>
```

I added this to my standalone.xml for Jboss 7 EAP:

```
configuration/standalone.xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/SomeDS" pool-name="SomeDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>{my-oracle-ldap-connection-url}</connection-url>
            <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
            <driver>ojdbc8.jar</driver>
            <security>
                <security-domain>jdbcDatabaseSecure</security-domain>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
            </validation>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            ????? should I put here my oracle driver?
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>
        ...
        <security-domain name="jdbcDatabaseSecure">
        ?????
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>

<management>
    <security-realms>
        ...
        <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="server_as_01.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="123456"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
</management>
```

Maybe less related 4.2.3 configs, but actual for SSL configuration:

```
{profile}/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml
<!-- SSL/TLS Connector configuration using the admin devl guide keystore -->
<Connector port="4570" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
    minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100" maxThreads="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
    keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server_as_01.keystore"
    keystorePass="123456" 
    truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server_as_01.keystore"
    truststorePass="123456" 
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Also I have these files in 4.2.3:

```
{profile}/conf/server.password
{profile}/conf/client.truststore
{profile}/conf/server_as_01.keystore
```

And `JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JBOSS_SERVER/conf/client.truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"`

I tried to do something similar with Jboss 7.0.0 EAP config, but as I've noticed from Google, there are too many differences in these implementations. It seems that JAAS does not exist in 7 EAP anymore.

Can someone help me with the correct config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to this guide for all the migration related issue you are facing. The recommendation is, you can first try to migrate to EAP 6 and then try it to migrate to EAP 7. 
Here's the guide to migrate from EAP 5.x to 7, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/migration_guide/migrating_from_older_releases